# How do I invoke a method on a C++ class pointer with swig wrappers?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap C++ code for use within a Python testing framework.  My problem is that I'm getting a pointer to an instance of a class that I need to then invoke methods on.  Eg, within my swig file example.i:

```
iExample* getMyClassInstance();

...

class iExample
{
    public:
        virtual void somePureVirtualMethod() = 0;
// ...
};
```

Now, in python, if I had the class, I could just call the method

```
myClassInstance.somePureVirtualMethod()
```

However, I don't actually have an instance of the class, of course.  I have an opaque pointer generated from SWIG.  How do I use it?  Obviously in Python I can't do

```
myClassInstancePtr = example.getMyClassInstance()
myClassInstancePtr->somePureVirtualMethod()
```

I tried using cpointer.i or pointer.i in swig to generate pointer functions, but that's no good, because it's trying to create copies of the class.  This can't even compile with an interface with pure virtual methods, and even if I wasn't using pure virtual methods, I don't want to create a copy of the class, I just want to invoke something on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG can handle this just fine.  Make sure you define the interface in SWIG and then it won't be opaque.  Here's a working example:

```
%module x

%inline %{

// Define the interface.
struct iExample
{
    virtual int somePureVirtualMethod() = 0;
};

iExample* getMyClassInstance();

%}

// Implementation, not exposed to Python
%{
struct Internal : public iExample
{
    int somePureVirtualMethod() { return 5; }
};
iExample* getMyClassInstance() { return new Internal(); }
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import x
>>> i = x.getMyClassInstance()
>>> i.somePureVirtualMethod()
5
```

However, this implementation will leak an Internal Instance.  You may want to implement a way to free it automatically.  One way is to use `%newobject` and define a virtual destructor.  Python will delete the object when there are no more references to it.

```
%module x

%newobject getMyClassInstance;

%inline %{
struct iExample
{
    virtual ~iExample() {};
    virtual int somePureVirtualMethod() = 0;
};
iExample* getMyClassInstance();
%}

// Implementation
%{
#include <iostream>
struct Internal : public iExample
{
    int somePureVirtualMethod() { return 5; }
    ~Internal() { std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl; }
};
iExample* getMyClassInstance() { return new Internal(); }
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import x
>>> i = x.getMyClassInstance()
>>> i.somePureVirtualMethod()
5
>>> i=2       # reassign i
destroyed     # garbage-collected
```

Comment: +1 Nicely explained. However, novices at SWIG may not understand how you are using %inline to create standalone .i (may benefit from a line of comment).

Comment: Right, I didn't realize that '.' can invoke methods on pointers in swigged C to Python code.  Tested it and it works.  If you need an explicit deference, my answer will do it, but if you just want to invoke a method on a pointer, pretend the pointer is a reference and use '.'.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer I've found is to edit your example.i to add in some helper functions to do dereferencing.  In your swig file example.i:

```
{%
...
// Helper function to dereference pointers within python
template <typename T>
T& dereference(T* ptr)
{
    return *ptr;
}
...  
%}
...
// Make every version of the templated functions we'll need
template <typename T> T& dereference(T* ptr);
%template(dereferencePtr_iExample) dereference<iExample>;
```

Now in python

```
myClassInstance = example.dereferencePtr_iExample(example.getMyClassInstance())
myClassInstance.somePureVirtualMethod()
```

I imagine this method should work generically for other languages like perl as well, and you don't have to screw around with SWIG typemaps.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to dereference. Dereferencing is a C++ concept specific to pointers, Python knows nothing about pointers, only references, so SWIG already takes care of that for you. Why isn't Mark's solution adequate? His doesn't use templates either.

Comment: I haven't looked at Mark's solution yet.  It was the weekend.  I have a family and hobbies outside of work.  I'll check it out this week, I've been working on other debugging today.  And the templates were just for a clean, generic solution.  My initial solution didn't use templates.  Is there a problem with templates?